# cmder startup: bug in init.bat?

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, cmder

I just started using cmder and I noticed that when it starts up it emits a bunch of error messages like this:

```
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

'"C:\Program Files (x86)\cmder\config\profile.d\"Loading"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

I dug around in the various startup files that were getting run, and I isolated the errors as coming from this block in init.bat (the one that the cmder install program created when I setup the program originally):

```
pushd "%CMDER_ROOT%\config\profile.d"
for /f "usebackq" %%x in ( `dir /b *.bat *.cmd 2^>nul` ) do (
  call :verbose-output Calling "%CMDER_ROOT%\config\profile.d\%%x"...
  call "%CMDER_ROOT%\config\profile.d\%%x"
)
popd
```

What's happening is that %%x is being passed the names of whatever files are found in the profile.d directory (initially there was none, so I added an empty cmd file that just echoed its name), the word "Loading" as well as an empty string.  I tinkered with the source of the current version of init.bat to determine this, and I've tried putting a conditional around the "call" part, like this, which doesn't work like I expect it to:

```
pushd "%CMDER_ROOT%\config\profile.d"
for /f "usebackq" %%x in ( `dir /b *.bat *.cmd 2^>nul` ) do (
  if "%%x" NEQ "" && "%%x" NEQ "Loading" (
      call :verbose-output Calling "%CMDER_ROOT%\config\profile.d\%%x"...
      echo "Calling %%x from init.bat..."
      call "%CMDER_ROOT%\config\profile.d\%%x"
  )
)
popd
```

I'm kinda stuck as to what to do to fix it (I write a lot of Unix/Linux shell scripts, but almost never write any Windows batch programs).  Besides, at the top of init.bat is this:

```
:: !!! THIS FILE IS OVERWRITTEN WHEN CMDER IS UPDATED
```

Is this a bug in init.bat?  Is this something about my setup that causes this? I also run cygwin on my PC, could that be contributing to this?

Does anyone have any suggestions about what is going on here and what I can do to fix it?

Addendum:

"Magoo" suggested this change:

if "%%x" NEQ "" IF "%%x" NEQ "Loading" ( ...

but that didn't work either; both the empty string and the "Loading" (which is actually "\"Loading") are still getting though.  Here's the edited block:

```
pushd "%CMDER_ROOT%\config\profile.d"
for /f "usebackq" %%x in ( `dir /b *.bat *.cmd 2^>nul` ) do (
  echo "Calling *%%x* from init.bat..."
  if "%%x" NEQ "" IF "%%x" NEQ "Loading" (
      call :verbose-output Calling "%CMDER_ROOT%\config\profile.d\%%x"...
      call "%CMDER_ROOT%\config\profile.d\%%x"
  )
)
popd
```

And here's what's now being output:

```
Calling ** from init.bat...
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.
Calling *"Loading* from init.bat...
'"C:\Program Files (x86)\cmder\config\profile.d\"Loading"' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

Addendum 2:

I think I've come up with one possible solution, a temporary one that should work until init.bat gets overwritten.  If I change the offending block to the following, it seems to work as it should:

```
pushd "%CMDER_ROOT%\config\profile.d"
for /f "usebackq" %%x in ( `dir /b *.bat *.cmd 2^>nul` ) do (
  IF DEFINED x IF EXIST "%%x" (
      call "%%x"
  )
)
popd
```

This still doesn't explain why the 2 offending strings ("" and "Loading) are being generated in the first place, but I'll settle for this...

Comment: If you are a beginner in Windows Batch files, I suggest you to start using the standard commands, and cmder is not one... You should review the cmder support for info related to its use and/or bugs.

Answer (score 1):

```
if "%%x" NEQ "" && "%%x" NEQ "Loading" (
```

won't work as you expect. `if` is very simple `if value op value dothis'

You'd need

```
if "%%x" NEQ "" IF "%%x" NEQ "Loading" (
```

That is, the second `if` is the `dothis` of the first, creating and `and` condition.

I'd suggest you `echo %%x` beforehand though - -to see the actual filename being processed.

As for its being overwritten - well, if you adjust it, the authors will overwrite it when they install updates - so save a copy and re-apply your changes.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but that didn't work either.  The both the empty string and the "Loading" (although it's actually "\"Loading") still get through

Comment: I'd suggest `%CMDER_ROOT%` contains a close-parenthesis. Since you have `pushd`'d to the directory, in the two `call` commands, replace the `%CMDER_ROOT%\config\profile.d` with `.` which means "current directory".

Comment: I made that change, but the the two strings causing the errors--the empty string and "Loading--are still getting past the double if

Comment: The fact is that `dir /b` shouldn't output empty lines, or lines that contain `"` as you report. Try `rem ` before the two `calls` to disable them and insert another `echo %%x` after the cascaded `if`s. I'm uncomfortable with the `for/f` command, too - try `for /f "delims=" %%x in ( 'dir /b /a-d *.bat *.cmd 2^>nul' ) do (` - conventional single-quotes and suppress the directory entries.